# How do i parse FB.UI string?

Tags: json, facebook, jsonp

```
[[Object { uid="*****", name="Vini Katyal", is_app_user=true, more...}, Object { uid="*****", name="Vinay Katyal", is_app_user=true, more...}, Object { uid="****", name="Aviral Kumar", is_app_user=true, more...}, 3 more...]]
```

How do i parse this response tried JSON.parse(response) doesn't work for me.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a JSON string. A JSON string should look like this:

```
{
    {"uid":"*****",
     "name":"Vini",
     "is_app_user":"true"},
    {"uid":"*****",
     "name":"Bla",
     "is_app_user":"true"}
}
```

Please check the documentation of the API you are accessing to see what kind of encoding is that.

Comment: Thanks about that information how do i parse the above string

Comment: JSON.parse or jQuery.parseJSON